# Lowering graphics card power consumpution

Tags: 11.04, ati

My laptop have Ati mobility HD4500 graphics card. I am using the Ati drivers. Still my palm rest is getting quite hotter compared to when I am using the windows. This is my graphics card is present under the palm rest. I have also change the "Power play" in the Catalyst control Center to maximum battery still no effect in Ubuntu. This works perfectly well in windows.

Can anyone pls suggest me how can I reduce my graphics card's power consumption or make it to run at lower temperature.

Comment: Able to resolve many power issue by installing the latest Graphics drivers from AMD.

Answer (score 1):

Answered by OP

Able to resolve many power issue by installing the latest Graphics drivers from AMD